# Fluid Progress bar animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently bust with creating a simple game where the user clicks a button as quick as possible and as the user clicks the progress bar should show the user the progress, the only problem is that the animation is very choppy.. Is there anyway to smooth out the animation?

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qUhya/)

and the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
var $counter = $('#counter');
var $button = $('#lemon-button');
var count = 2;
var speed = 70;
//test for ie7 an ie8
if (!$.support.leadingWhitespace) {
    var countAddStep = 5;
//test for ie7 an ie8
}else{
    var countAddStep = 3;
}
var timeout;

    func = function () {
    count--;
    $counter.text(count);
    if(count <= 4) {
        jQuery('.bar').height(400);
    }
    if(count >= 5) {
        jQuery('.bar').height(350);
    }
    if(count > 6) {
        jQuery('.bar').height(300);
    }
    if(count > 8) { 
        jQuery('.bar').height(200);
    }
    if(count > 12) {
        jQuery('.bar').height(100);
    }
    if(count > 14) {
        jQuery('.bar').height(20);
    }
    if(count > 15) {
        jQuery('.bar').height(0);
        alert("finish");
    }

    if(count !== 0) {
        timeout = setTimeout(func, speed);
        }
    };

    $button.on('click', function() {
        count = count+countAddStep;
        $counter.text(count);
        if (count === countAddStep) {
            count++;
            func();
        }
    });
func();
});
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use animate for it and came up with a working solution on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCwhU/2/). The main problem is, that animation which are smooth need time. But in your example time is really important, so you need to keep an eye on the animation time...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
var $counter = $('#counter');
var $button = $('#lemon-button');
var count = 2;
var speed = 70;
//test for ie7 an ie8
if (!$.support.leadingWhitespace) {
var countAddStep = 5;
//test for ie7 an ie8
}else{
var countAddStep = 3;
}
var timeout;

func = function () {
count--;
$counter.text(count);
if(count <= 4) {
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 400, opacity: 1}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
}
if(count >= 5) {
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 350, opacity: 1}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
}
if(count > 6) {
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 300, opacity: 1}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
}
if(count > 8) { 
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 200, opacity: 1}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
}
if(count > 12) {
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 100, opacity: 1}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
}
if(count > 14) {
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 20, opacity: 1}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
}
if(count > 15) {
    jQuery('.bar').animate({height: 0, opacity: 1}, 100, function() {alert("finish");});    }

if(count !== 0 && count <= 15) {
    timeout = setTimeout(func, speed);
    }
};

$button.on('click', function() {
    count = count+countAddStep;
    $counter.text(count);
    if (count === countAddStep) {
        count++;
        func();
    }
});
func();
});
```

Comment: Works perfect thank you!!! Just a question, Is there a way to make the bar stay full after its full?

Comment: Let me try, I will post here as soon as I found a solution :-)

Comment: Try the updated JSFiddle, the bar should stay as soon as it reach maximum value.

Comment: I have changed line 37/38 (added alert as finish function) and line 40 (checking if count <= 15) in JSFiddle.